# Decimal to roman python

Tags: python, roman-numerals

I'm a beginner as you can see and I would like to know how I can improve my code. Studying for 6 months now. Thank you.

```
roman_dict = {1: 'I', 4: 'IV',  5: 'V', 9: 'IX', 10: 'X', 40: 'XL', 50: 'L', 90: 'XC', 100: 'C', 400: 'CD',
              500: 'D', 900: 'CM', 1000: 'M'}

divide_list = [1000, 100, 10, 1]

def not_in_dict(fixed_decimal, divide_num):
    sub_count = 0
    sub_roman_multi = roman_dict[divide_num]
    temp_decimal = fixed_decimal
    while temp_decimal not in roman_dict:
        temp_decimal -= divide_num
        sub_count += 1
    return roman_dict[temp_decimal]+(sub_count*sub_roman_multi)

def decimal_to_roman(decimal):
    original_decimal = decimal
    roman = ""
    for divide_num in divide_list:
        if decimal >= divide_num:
            reminder = decimal//divide_num
            if(reminder >= 1) and ((reminder*divide_num) in roman_dict):
                roman += roman_dict[(reminder*divide_num)]
                decimal -= reminder*divide_num
            else:
                roman += not_in_dict(reminder*divide_num, divide_num)
                decimal -= (reminder*divide_num)
    return str(original_decimal)+' = '+roman
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a list of tuples instead of a dictionary and reverse the order, you can simply iterate over it. Your `while` loop also becomes a lot easier to understand and there is no longer any need to outsource it to another function that returns the literal and its count.

Instead of manually adding strings ([something you should basically never do in in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)), use `str.join`.

```
ROMAN_LITERALS = [(1000, 'M'), (900, 'CM'), (500, 'D'), (400, 'CD'), (100, 'C'),
                  (90, 'XC'),  (50, 'L'), (40, 'XL'), (10, 'X'), (9, 'IX'),
                  (5, 'V'), (4, 'IV'), (1, 'I')]

def decimal_to_roman(x):
    out = []
    for value, literal in ROMAN_LITERALS:
        while x >= value:
            x -= value
            out.append(literal)
    return "".join(out)
```

Instead of the `while` loop you can also use integer division like you did:

```
def decimal_to_roman(x):
    out = []
    for value, literal in ROMAN_LITERALS:
        n = x // value               # will be 0 if value is too large
        out.extend([literal] * n)    # will not do anything if n == 0
        x -= n * value               # will also not do anything if n == 0
    return "".join(out)
```

Comment: wow. looks so easy now, thank you. that's great.

Comment: @Ofeks: If this helped you, consider accepting it as the correct answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer). It is customary to wait about 24 hours, though, to give everyon on the globe a chance to answer and not discourage other people from commenting.